# Best/Most adequate way to operate numbers taken from database in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, optimization, sequelize.js

My task is to take two numbers obtained from a quite complex pair of sequelize count queries (of around 25 lines each) and do a simple subtraction.

This happens on an express.js controller, and I'm wondering which is the best way to do it, taking in consideration to make it readable but clever and functional.

Keep in mind that this subtraction result will later be used as condition in a third sequelize query. So, bonus points if the controller stays somewhat clean and performing.

Some ideas as promises, but observables are also welcome:

```
            //OP1
            var result = (
                await (Table1.count(sequelize_query1)) -
                await (Table2.count(sequelize_query2))
            );
```

```
            //OP2
            var result = await (
                Table1.count(sequelize_query1)
            ) - (
                Table2.count(sequelize_query2)
            );
```

```
            //OP3
            var number1 = await Table1.count(sequelize_query1);
            var number2 = await Table2.count(sequelize_query2);
            var result = number1-number2;
```

Comment: they the same (ignoring the missing await). OP3 I would use if you have 25 of them, though id put them in a result object not append numbers to vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I hear "clever" about this sort of computation, I cringe. I've been clever like that, but not clever enough, a few times. It doesn't end well.

Please, with this kind of computation, make your code as clear and easy-to-read as you can. Clear logic is by far the best way, and maybe the only way, to know you have it exactly right.

If it were me, I would write a SQL VIEW that yielded the answer. That's because I work in a place where people know SQL, and we can read it.

In your case, writing `async` functions (your third choice) lets you write clear step-by-step code with `await` operations.

It's twice as hard to debug code as it is to write it. So don't use all your talent ad cleverness  writing code, or you'll never be able to debug it.

Comment: I'm around the same midset as you, specially taking in count im the only one mantaining the docs updated.
The question was based in curiosity, mostly. I know i can solve it pretty fast and clean with a Promise.all() and the OP3, i just was wondering if there was a more interesting/performing/clean way to do it. 
That said, it's nice to see people thinking somewhat similarly about consequences.
Thank you!